# Trying to delete an excel worksheet and recreate it, but throws an error that the name already exists

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, automation

**Edit:** Ended up finding out what was causing it, but unsure why this works. The fix was to add this line after the excel object was created:

```
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
```

I'm using PowerShell and trying to delete an existing excel worksheet and then recreate it. My environment is locked down for modules, so unfortunately I can't use ImportExcel or other similar modules. I'm a bit new to PowerShell so apologies if the code is messy, but here's what I currently have:

```
$TodaysDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

# Open a new excel object
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $False

# If a workbook does not already exist, create one
# If a workbook does exist, open it.

if (-not(Test-Path -Path $ExistingExcelFile -PathType Leaf)) {
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
    # Delete the automatically generated sheet
    $workbook.WorkSheets.Item("Sheet1").Delete()
} else {
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExistingExcelFile)
}

# If a worksheet with todays date already exists, delete it so we can start fresh
if (($TodaysDate -in $($workbook.Worksheets).Name)) {
    $TodaysWrkSheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Item($TodaysDate)
    $TodaysWrkSheet.Activate()
    $TodaysWrkSheet.Delete()
}

#Add the worksheet and set the name
$WrkSheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Add()
$WrkSheet.Name = $TodaysDate

# If the summary page exists, delete it so we can start fresh
if (("Summary" -in $($workbook.Worksheets).Name)) {
    $SummaryWrkSheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Item("Summary")
    $SummaryWrkSheet.Activate()
    $SummaryWrkSheet.Delete()
}

$SummaryPage = $workbook.Worksheets.Add()
$SummaryPage.Name = "Summary"
```

This is the error I get when it tries to create the new sheet with todays date:

> That name is already taken. Try a different one.

The second part with the summary page works fine and it finds/deletes/recreates it, so I'm assuming it's a problem with $TodaysDate, but why? The if statement block of code for `($TodaysDate -in $($workbook.Worksheets).Name)` gets hit, would there be a problem with `$TodaysWrkSheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Item($TodaysDate)`? It creates the sheet just fine as long as it doesn't exist already, so it at least doesn't complain creating a sheet name with $TodaysDate. I've been trying for a while to figure out why but haven't been having any luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) what could make you life much easier? Regardless of that - when you deleted the worksheet you would need to save the file to make the change permanent, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Olaf Unfortunately I'm not able to use any outside modules (including the entire Powershell Gallery) due to workplace restrictions.
  
I have tried saving first before adding the new worksheet, but still get an error that the name is already in use. I'm unsure why I don't get the same error with the summary page as it deletes and recreates as it should and looks identical to how I did it with $TodaysDate.

Comment: I'd  see two options - discuss the restrictions with your IT department. Those restrictions do nat make any sense when you need external modules for your work or simply use another name. ;-)

Comment: I ended up finding a solution, but I'm not sure why it works. The solution was to add `$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False` to the object.
  
I'll definitely be reaching out to them as having access to modules would make my life so much easier.. :)

Comment: You may invite them to review/verify/inspect/audit the module before they approve it. ;-)  Good luck!   :-)